# What can one do with data in the order of incremental complexity?

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, inference

For myself I try to create a list of statistical methods that can be applied to the data. In would like to go from the simplest and basic methods to more complex ones.

In the simplest case we have an unordered set of numbers. What can one do with that? Well, we can calculate mean, variance and moments of higher order (skewness, kurtosis and so on). But ideally one would like to have a probability distribution, it would be the most complete description of the observed data set (in the sense that such parameters as mean, variance and so on come form the distribution). If one cannot get the complete distribution, one might want at least to know if there is a statistically significant deviation from the normal (or any other) distribution.

Now one step further in the complexity. We have a set of pairs of real numbers: `(x, y)`. First of all we can consider each of the two variables independently and do all the stuff that I have described above. Second, we can try to find out if there is a relation between `x` and `y`. Thirds, we can calculate correlations to find out if there is a linear component in the relation between `x` and `y`.

Can one say that correlations (or co-variance) should be considered as first order terms in the relation between `x` and `y`? If it is the case, how can we calculate higher order terms in the relation?

Like in the case of a set of numbers, in case of a set of tuples, in the ideal case we would like to have a 2D distribution.

If one of the variables in a tuple is categorical and another one is real, the interesting question to answer is: Is there statistically significant difference  between the sets of real numbers corresponding to different categories. So, it is in the direction of ANOVA.

What else can we do with the data? Do we have something qualitatively new if we have a set of triplets: `(x, y, z)`?

**ADDED**

What I actually try to get is to organize somehow different statistical methods, to have a more general picture of what can one do with data. It looks to me like there is a huge set of different statistical methods. But can one somehow classify them, formalize them, organize them? I do not want to get a system for everything. A system for just basic methods is fine to me.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [General Linear Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model)? It encapsulates a lot of what you are talking about.

Comment: @GuðmundurEinarsson, in the linear model we assume that some components of the data vector depend on other components of data vector in a linear way. Let us say we have data in the following form: $(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n, y_1, y_2, \cdots , y_n)$ and we assume that all $y_j$ are linear functions of $x_i$. Then we calculate the parameters of these linear functions. But I do not understand what exactly do we cover (or encapsulate) in this way.

Comment: Note that this is not just a linear model, it includes many more models then multiple linear regression, i.e. "The general linear model incorporates a number of different statistical models: ANOVA, ANCOVA, MANOVA, MANCOVA, ordinary linear regression, t-test and F-test." So it is just a matter of how you set up the data for the General Linear Model, then you can get different results corresponding to different models.

Comment: That means that the General Linear Model encapsulates a lot of other basic models, i.e. it generalizes many models that may seem quite different, and "puts it under the same hat".